# Permission to only read Wallet Address

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I just want to collect the user's Wallet Address. I think these permission are too much. I don't need to see balance or initiate transactions. Just read-wallet-address.

What is the easiest and clean way to get the wallet address?
This is the code I am using:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
signer = provider.getSigner()
const walletAddress = await signer.getAddress()
```

[image: See wallet balance, activity and initiate transactions]

Answer (score 1):

This is currently the only option. There's no "read address but cannot request transactions" permission type. Your code is correct.

Docs: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-requestaccounts

Comment: Is there a way I could just make someone sign a message and get their wallet address, like a login?

Comment: @VishwasSinghChouhan It's the other way around. You need to pass the signer address as a part of the request (to sign a message) to MetaMask.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout our new opensource plugin to MetaMask, it enables you to “fake” any wallet address, search for “TresConnect MetaMask Impersonator” in the Chrome Extensions Store.

Or go directly - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tresconnect-metamask-impe/dcncbippcdfiljhcfpdieipdjfjoaihl?hl=en-GB&authuser=0